# Reading data from multiple .txt files with c++

Tags: c++, unix, filereader

I need to extract a series of information from multiple files (64 files) in a directory. Each file consists of several lines like:

Pair of Operators: 0& ins: 0& rmv: 0&  weight: 0.124354

Pair of Operators: 1& ins: 1& rmv: 0&  weight: 0.00672458

Pair of Operators: 2& ins: 2& rmv: 0&  weight: 0.000467531

...

The information is stored in a vector. I wrote a code, however, I receive a segmentation fault error. Here is my code. Could anyone indicate where the problem comes from?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

struct info {
    char* name;
    vector<vector<double>> weights; // dest-const-weight
};

int main(int c, char* v[]) {
    struct dirent* pDirent;
    DIR* pDir;
    char buffer[50];
    strcpy(buffer, v[1]);

   if (c < 2) {
      printf ("Usage: testprog <dirname>\n");
      return 1;
   }

   pDir = opendir (buffer);

   if (pDir == NULL) {
       printf ("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", v[1]);
       return 1;
   }

    vector<info> Information;
    for (int inst = 0; inst < 64; inst++) {
        info temp;
        temp.weights.resize(9);
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            temp.weights[j].resize(4);
        Information.push_back(temp);
    }
    int cmp = 0;
    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") != 0 &&
            strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") != 0) {
            char line[1024];
            ifstream file(pDirent->d_name);
            Information[cmp].name = pDirent->d_name;
            int oper = -1;
            int dest = -1;
            int ins = -1;
            double weight = -1;

            for (int l = 0; l < 36; l++) {
                file.getline(line, 1024);
                // cout<<line<<endl;
                sscanf(line,
                       "Pair of Operators: %d& ins: %d& rmv: %d&  weight: %f",
                       &oper, &dest, &ins, &weight);
                // sscanf(line, "%*s %d%*s %d%*s %d%*S %f", &oper, &dest, &ins,
                // &weight);
                // cout<<oper<<"   "<<dest<<"   "<<ins<<"   "<<weight<<endl;
                Information[cmp].weights[dest][ins] = weight;
            }
            cmp++;
        }
    }

    closedir(pDir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is executing at the time of the segmentation fault?

Comment: I think it's from this line:     ifstream file(pDirent->d_name);

Answer (score 1):

I can see two obvious seg faults.
First of all you copy `v[1]` into buffer. Do you provide any arguments to your program?
Second one I see on the fly is that you try to call readdir on a uninitialized pointer of DIR.
Try `DIR* pDir = opendir(...);`

You should always print a usage message when the argument count doesnt match!

```
if (c != 1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s needs exactly one argument!\n" v[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

One more thing I forgot to mention. You can compile your program with the `-g` flag and try to use a debugger to find these errors.

Comment: I provide the name of the directory from which the files are supposed to be read as an argument. This is a subdirectory of the main.cpp directory. I'm wondering if ifstream file(pDirent->d_name); looks for the file in the right directory or not!

Comment: If you want to provide the path start off with the if conditional I posted above. Then initialize the `DIR* pDir = opendir(v[1]);` followed by `if (!pDir) { perror("Dir not found.\n"); return 1; }` to see if the directory was found or not.

Comment: First of all make sure that your code compiles, because you missed a space at the definition of weights `vector<vector<double> >`. After that rethink what you do here `Information[cmp].weights[dest][ins] = weight;` Try to print the values. I guess you get some `-1` values that cause the program to crash.

Comment: when I print "line", it is empty. I think the file has not been opened at all.

Comment: when I print "line" at the beginning of the last "for", it is an empty line. So all the values of "oper", "dest" and "weight" remain -1. I think the file has not been opened at all. I'm wondering if ifstream file(pDirent->d_name); its job or not!